# Working with function in C++

Tags: c++

please help to solve this basic problem. I received a question below.

Calculate modulus of A and B integers to 1,000,000,007 using function F(A, B, N) as explained below using C++ with 0 <= N <= 1000000000.

```
Modulus of F[A, B, 0] is equal to A%1,000,000,007
Modulus of F[A, B, 1] is equal to B%1,000,000,007
Modulus of F[A, B, N] is equal to modulus of F[A, B, N - 1] + F[A, B, N - 2]

Example, Modulus of F[3, 4, 5] is equal to 29. In detail:

Modulus of F[3, 4, 0] is equal to 3%1,000,000,007 which is 3

Modulus of F[3, 4, 1] is equal to 4%1,000,000,007 which is 4

Modulus of F[3, 4, 2] is equal to modulus of F[3, 4, 1] + F[A, B, 0] which is 3 + 4 = 7

Modulus of F[3, 4, 3] is equal to modulus of F[3, 4, 2] + F[A, B, 1] which is 7 + 4 = 11

Modulus of F[3, 4, 4] is equal to modulus of F[3, 4, 3] + F[A, B, 2] which is 11 + 7 = 18

Modulus of F[3, 4, 5] is equal to modulus of F[3, 4, 4] + F[A, B, 3] which is 18 + 11 = 29
```

I used Xcode and Mac OS X and here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int solution(int A, int B, int N)
{
    std::vector<int> remainderVector;

    if (N < 0 || N > 1000000000)
    {
        std::cout << "N is out of range." << std::endl;
    }

    if (N == 0)
    {
        remainderVector[N] = A%1000000007;
    }

    if (N == 1)
    {
        remainderVector[N] = B%1000000007;
    }

    if (N > 1 && N <= 1000000000)
    {
        remainderVector[0] = A%1000000007;
        remainderVector[1] = B%1000000007;

        for (int i = 2; i <= N; i++)
        {
            remainderVector[i] = remainderVector[i - 1] + remainderVector[i - 2];
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Remainder is: " << remainderVector[N] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Input A interger: " << std::endl;
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;

    std::cout << "Input B interger: " << std::endl;
    int y;
    std::cin >> y;

    std::cout << "Input Z interger: " << std::endl;
    int z;
    std::cin >> z;

    int solution(int x, int y, int z);

    std::cout << "This is a debug message." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code it just appeared message: This is a debug message. Why it did not print out number 29 when I input example of 3, 4, 5 as explained above.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Did you debug your program?

Comment: Your call to the "solution" is a prototype declaration, not a function call. Try  with "solution(x, y, z);" I'm surprised this is compiling tough.

Comment: Thanks, I changed to solution( x, y, z) and it works when I also declare size of vector to N + 1. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your `remainderVector` is initially empty, so you can't assign to arbitrary elements within it (since they don't exist). Change:

```
std::vector<int> remainderVector;
```

to

```
std::vector<int> remainderVector(N + 1);
```

Also note that the logic in the remaining code looks a little muddled and has some redundancy. A fixed/simplified version would be:

```
remainderVector[0] = A%1000000007; // set element 0

if (N > 0)                         // set element 1 
{
    remainderVector[1] = B%1000000007;
}

for (int i = 2; i <= N; i++)       // set elements 2..N
{
    remainderVector[i] = remainderVector[i - 1] + remainderVector[i - 2];
}
```

Comment: I changed the size of vector to N + 1 and it works. I did not put size of vector because it is explained that vector can understand its size automatically or no need to specify its size when initiating. Here is the link that I studied http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/6-16-an-introduction-to-stdvector/.

Comment: A `std::vector` will automatically increase in size if you use e.g. `push_back` to add an element, but you can't just randomly index it beyond its current size and expect it to automatically grow to accommodate this.

Comment: Hi Paul, now I understand that "it is Not able to index vector randomly beyond its current size" as you explained. Thank for teaching me push_back. In the link I provided above, you will see that the author never specifies vector size. In your code to set element 0, element 1 and element i, you did not use push_back. It really a mess for me. By the way I learnt a good lesson. Thank you very much Paul.

Comment: I think in this case we just use Array because we know the size of the collection N + 1. When we do not know the size of the collection, we use Vector and we can add elements into vector using push_back. It is now reasonable to me that why Alex at learncpp.com did not mention about specifying the size of vector when initiating it.